# How to use --preproxy on PHP/cURL/Guzzle

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I want to make a chain proxy request (with a proxy calling the actual proxy).

With a raw curl command I would do:

```
curl --preproxy "socks5://1234:5678" --proxy "http://1234:5678" "http://example.org"
```

But PHP doesn't recognize the curlopt `CURLOPT_PRE_PROXY` (nor `CURLOPT_PREPROXY`) as per https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PRE_PROXY.html.

The option was implemented on curl `v7.52.0` and my installed curl is `v7.54.0`.

How may I achieve the same command above but from PHP's curl lib or from the GuzzleHttp Client?

Comment: My guess is PHP still doesn't support preproxy therefore, no `CURLOPT_PREPROXY` constant.

Comment: Yeah, the only way I managed to make it work was executing `curl` itself. Not happy at all with this solution though.